# Each one of you - his / your

Tags: possessives, exam-questions

Which sentence is correct ?

**Each one of you must make up his mind.**

Or

**Each one of you must make up your mind.**

From the knowledge I have , Each is followed by *his* but since here we have **one of you** so will it will take *your* instead of *his* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each one of you** makes it clear that you are directly addressing a group of people. When directly addressing people, the possessive to use is **your**. Unless, that is, each person is being tasked with convincing a male third party of something, in which case *his* can be used. This context must already have been established for this usage though.

If you are *not* directly addressing people, but are instead reporting about a group of people, then you would not use *you* and *your*, you would instead use *them* and *their* or say "Each one must make up their mind" (without the *them*).

I would tend to steer clear of *his*/*her* in this situation unless it is made clear at the start of the sentence that the group is all male or all female, and even then I might still use *their*.

Comment: Shouldn't we use His in place of their in the example you gave ? Each one must make up his mind ?

Comment: @user212388 You can if they are all male. There is no "proper" gender-neutral, third person, singular pronoun, so if they are not all of the same gender, use _their_.

Comment: @user212388 While it was once acceptable and normal to use male pronouns to refer to someone of indeterminate gender or an individual in a mixed-gender group, in the past few decades that usage has dropped significantly, at least in AmE.  Using "his" can come across as both antiquated and sexist.  The "singular they" is the most common way to express a gender neutral singular pronoun in modern speech, with "he or she" probably the second most common.

Answer (score 1):

**Each one of you must make up your mind.** Is the correct sentence.

If you say the first then a question rises: Who's mind and how is each one of them going to make it up?

Comment: This answer is correct but lacks explanation *why* it is correct.

Comment: I believe "his" is also correct, but it's refering to somebody else. (well it's quite illogical to make up someone else mind.)